# Nodejs - Adding columns to a table, without migrations?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm currently using Nodejs and Sequelize, and when I want to add a new column to an existing table, I:

1. Modify the model for the table
2. Add a migration to add a column to the table

But is there another way to do this, and not have to worry about the "migrations" all the time? The thing I'm seeing is that people have to make sure the database columns are the same in both the model and in the migrations file. I want to only modify the database schema in the model, and have it update the database (just like Hibernate does in Java).

I've seen how sequelize can drop a table and recreate it (within the model file). . . but I don't want to do that since I have data in the tables I want to keep. Is there some other library that I can accomplish this, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to add a new column, you can just change the model and it will add the column automatically.